# Website Browser Tracker

Tags: php, html, database, browser, registration

I want to keep a track of what browsers access my website. I have a database that stores the user information after they register on the website, along with the data they enter in the form I also want to store what browser they used to access and register on the website. Is there actually any way to do that, for a website to see what browser is being used and save that information?

Comment: @Blazemonger, Don't use `get_browser()` anymore.  The data it relies on is `browscap.ini`, which is no longer updated.

Comment: Richard, have you considered a proper solution, such as Google Analytics?  There are many free analytics packages.  If you don't need to use that data directly in your application, that is the way to go.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can't definitively know what browser a user is using, you can only know what the browser is reporting itself as being named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_browser()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

This will return what browser is being used

From the docs:

"Attempts to determine the capabilities of the user's browser, by looking up the browser's information in the browscap.ini file."

UPDATE:

As @ Brad pointed out, this function isn't reliable anymore. You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`.

Comment: Don't use this anymore.  The data it relies on is `browscap.ini`, which is no longer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Brad. What's the alternative?

Comment: That depends on the need.  If you just need analytics to optimize your site with, then I would use an analytics package, such as Google Analytics.  If you had some specific reason to track data on users browsers and use that in your application, then you need to parse the user-agent string.  How you parse it and what you do with that information depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: @Brad agreed about an analytics package. I also updated my answer.

Comment: @Brad what exactly does analytics TELL me? Like does it have a list of all the browsers and then a tally for how many people accessed the site with a certain browser

Comment: @Richard An analytics package will give you that info. http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: @Richard, Yes, exactly.  It tells you just about everything you can know about your visitors.

Comment: @Richard, You have what set up?  Google Analytics?  If so, go to http://www.google.com/analytics, login, select your site's profile, under Audience, choose Technology, Browser & OS.